# Protege. How to make a list of properties for class?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

Good day. I have operations and performers in my ontology. Each performer can perform operation with different level of perfomance. I want that each performer have a list of congruence between operations and level of their perfomance. How can I make such object property correctly?

Comment: It's not really clear at all what you're asking.  Can you show your ontology and some example data?  Can you show a (mocked up) example of the kind of output you'd like to generate?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I'm so sorry but I dont know how to illustrate exept owl code, because StackOverflow doesn't allow me to post images.
And, another worlds, I want when parse OWL code that each performer had a list of confirmity between type of operation and level of perfomance.